# Create temporary file in C++

Tags: android, c++, ios

I need to create a temporary file, fill it with some data and send the result to a function that accepts only `std::istreams`.

I tried using [tmpfile()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpfile) and it works for my first requirement - 'create a file and fill it with some data', but it returns a `FILE*` and there is no way to convert it (as far as I know) to `std::streams`.

**Is there a C++ way of creating a temporary file?**
**If this is not possible, how reliable is [tmpnam](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpnam) to return a valid file name? Did anyone test this on Android or iOS?**

EDIT: I don't want to copy the data to `std::stringstream` as a part of my test is reading the data from the disk.

Comment: "*send the result to a function that accepts only std::istreams.*" Not a file, but: Do you know istringstream?

Comment: I don't want to copy the data. A part of my tests is reading from disk...

Comment: Is there any particular reason you believe that `tmpnam` won't do what you want?

Comment: @MatsPetersson No. The only reason I prefer to create a temp file is to avoid adding the code to delete it after I'm done with the tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an alternative to `std::tmpfile` or `std::tmpnam`, you might want to look at the [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library. It contains a function [unique_path()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#unique_path) that will give you a place to put directories, files, etc.

It also includes other filesystem manipulation features that the standard library doesn't have, like iterating over files in a directory. I've found these especially useful for unit tests.

Comment: one should note that the use of boost::filesystem::unique_path() is discouraged, as is the use of the original C library calls: it poses a security risk.  This is addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316527/what-is-the-c17-equivalent-to-boostfilesystemunique-path  --  in the end the way to handle these is to use calls that generate a filename and open it atomically, returning an open file pointer.