# What is the C++17 equivalent to boost::filesystem::unique_path()?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-filesystem, std-filesystem

`std::filesystem` on C++17, and `std::experimental::filesystem` for many pre-C++17 compilers, are based on `boost::filesystem` and almost all of it is obvious to port to the newer std.

But I see no `std::filesystem` equivalent to `boost::filesystem::unique_path()`.

Is there an equivalent in std that I'm not noticing? Or is there a recommended approach I should take to mimic the implementation?

I'm really hoping to replace the `boost::filesystem` dependency when my code notices it's compiling on a platform that supports `std::filesystem`, and `unique_path()` is the only not obvious part of my conversion.

Answer (score 25):

`unique_path` was removed because it was a potential attack vector for malware. There is a window of opportunity between calling `unique_path` and opening a file at that location during which some other process could create the same file. Depending on what the user does with the file, this may or may not constitute a security vulnerability. A similar issue exists with the POSIX function [`tmpnam`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpnam.3.html).

As noted in [this discussion](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/lwg/issue2633), this issue will be dealt with in the next iteration of the [Filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) library. Until then, you can either continue using [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), use the [`std::tmpnam`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpnam) function provided in [`<cstdio>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdio), or use safer platform-specific alternatives like [`mkstemp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell there is really no exact equivalent in C++17.

You didn't really specify what exactly you want to do but if you just need to store a temporary file *somewhere* then you should be able to mimic a similar functionality with `std::filesystem::temp_directory_path` which you can append with a randomly generated filename (which you can do [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12468109/2047610), or modify it accordingly if you require the exact same naming format as `boost::filesystem::unique_path()`)

Or if you just need to store *any* temporary file, you can use `std::tmpfile`.